# Node.js puppeteer - Transforming the fetch URL

Tags: automation, puppeteer

Original URL : 
https://goto-example.com/a/r/Acc/0017A000WCJrHQAX/view

I need to modify my url to 
https://goto--example.com/a/r/Acc/0017A000WCJrHQAX/related/Opportunities/view

I need to replace ' /view' from the original url and replace it with 'related/Opportunities/view'. 
Is there any other function in pupeeteer to modify the URL and continue my execution

please help

Answer (score 0):

You can use `setRequestIntercept` and the `request` event. For instance, this piece of code will return the same image for every image request:

```js
await page.setRequestInterception(true);
page.on('request', request => {
    const url = request.url().endsWith('.jpg')
        ? 'https://www.random.com/5C4AV43S2VE7JBPCD6H3LZDSM4.jpg'
        : request.url();
    request.continue({ url });
});
```